# How can I use autoload.php in google app engine (php)?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, storage, gcloud, autoloader

I'm new to app engine and trying create a php app from a sample code.
Can anyone please tell me what is the use of

require_once **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';

Is this set of libraries we need to download? 
I'm developing/test locally and deploying in to gcloud project using 'gcloud app deploy'

I can use 
use google\appengine\api\users\User;

but I cannot use
use google\cloud\storage\StorageClient;

Fatal error: Class 'google\cloud\storage\StorageClient' not found in C:\Users..

Is there a component to install for cloud storage?

Thanks

Comment: Hi George,

Thank you for your advice. 
ACtually even after deploying project in to my google project I get the same issue.
That's why I thought it's something to do with gcloud app engine setting.
Because according to my understanding in google app engine all the libraries are available by default. Aren't it?
This is my project and I get the same error.
https://assignment2-s3682248.appspot.com/ 

Chears
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice.
ACtually even after deploying project in to my google project I get the
same issue.
That's why I thought it's something to do with gcloud app engine setting.
Because according to my understanding in google app engine all the
libraries are available by default. Aren't it?
This is my project and I get the same error.
https://assignment2-s3682248.appspot.com/
https://rb.tc/4YY3B#https://assignment2-s3682248.appspot.com/

Chears
Sam

On Fri, Sep 27, 2019 at 4:27 AM 'George (Cloud Platform Support)' via
Google App Engine  wrote:

> As PHP scripts run relative to the current path,  not to the path of
>   script itself, you can use **DIR** to change this behavior, so that include
>   refers to the script's own path, as a result.
>
> StorageClient not found error is likely due to the absence of Cloud
>   Storage Client Libraries
>   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries, which you'll
>   have to install.
>
> This discussion group is oriented more towards general opinions, trends,
>   and issues of general nature touching the app engine. For coding in PHP,
>   and program architecture, as well as importing Cloud Storage Client
>   Libraries, you may be better served in dedicated forums such as
>   stackoverflow, where experienced programmers are within reach and ready to
>   help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if your question has already been answered (since I see you posted an answer that a GCP support agent gave you) but you didn't accept it.

If you are new with App Engine/PHP I would recommend to follow the documentation's [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart) to get a simple project up and running and then you can start modifying it accordingly to your requirements.

From the questions I could find on your post, how to use the ["autoload"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/building-app/#composer) of composer with [DIR](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/building-app/#initializing) and how to use the [Cloud Storage lib](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/building-app/#using-storage) in your app. I recommend to carefully read the documentation I have referenced (the three are from the same documentation but on specific parts) which describes the step by step on how to build your application.